# jquery how to only allow effect on assigned div, not children

Tags: jquery, html, children, effect

I have applied an mouseenter effect to a div. When you enter the div, it then animates another div. The problem is, the mouseenter effect applies to the children div as well. How do I apply the effect to just the parent div, but animate the children div?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft').mouseenter(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).children();
      $lefty.stop().animate({ 
        left: "0px",
  top: "0px"
             }, 400 );
  });
  $('#slideleft').mouseleave(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).children();
      $lefty.stop().animate({ 
        left: "-700px",
  top: "200px"
             }, 400 );
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="slideleft" class="slide"> 

  <div class="inner">Animate this element's left style property</div> 
</div> 



    </div>
```

Comment: You may want to rethink this entire thing. If you hover over a child, you're hovering over its parent first.

Comment: Hi there...glad to help, but could you clarify exactly what the UNdesired effect is? Are the '.inner' elements undergoing too many animations, is the parent undergoing too many animations? is it something else? (I think you may have used "effect" where you meant "event" above)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/udufa View that. Hover over the yellow box, then follow the green box as it exits bottom left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only apply the animation to the outer div, you can check the target of the event to make sure it matches the div that you selected in your jQuery method.
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.target

Here is what your code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft').mouseenter(function(event) {  // added 'event' as param name
        if ( this == event.target )             // ADD THIS LINE
        {
            var $lefty = $(this).children();
            $lefty.stop().animate({
                                    left: "0px",
                                    top: "0px"
                                  }, 400 );
        }
  });

  $('#slideleft').mouseleave(function(event) {
      // uncomment the below IF statement, if you only want to hide
      //  the inner div when mousing out of the outer div.
      // Otherwise the code as is will hide your div if you mouse out of either
      //  the outer or the inner div

      //if ( this == event.target )
      //{
        var $lefty = $(this).children();
        $lefty.stop().animate({
                                left: "-700px",
                                top: "200px"
                              }, 400 );
      //}
  });

});
```

PS: You have an extra closing DIV tag in your example HTML that is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty much what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the children firing the mousenter/mouseout events by not using them, and using the [jQuery .hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) function on your main div.

```
jQuery('#slideleft').hover(
        function() {
                // mouse over function
        },
        function() {
                // mouse leave function
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'stopPropagation' on the children like so:

```
$('#slideleft *').mouseenter(function(event) {        <---- note the asterisk selector
 event.stopPropagation();                        <---- this line
});
```

This prevents the mouseenter event from each child propagating to the parent. Here's the documentation for it:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

P.S. It counts a lot to be polite in stackoverflow. If I interpreted a bit of an ambiguous tone in some of your responses above correctly, then you might want to consider your words a little more in the future ;-), :-)

Comment: Thank you for the comments... I apologize about the vague responses. My problem is that it propagates to the children. The effect is applied to the parent, so it makes sense that it would apply to the children. I guess I am not sure how to structure it so you can hover over a larger "parent" div container and have another div fly into it without them having a parent/child relationship